# Do we need a "treatment" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are (at this writing) 8 questions tagged [treatment](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/treatment).  I'm having trouble seeing what this tag adds to questions that are already tagged [health](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health), [behavior](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behavior), [care](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/care), [safety](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/safety), [injury](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/injury), etc.

Do we need this tag?  If so, what is its purpose?

Tagged Questions:

- [Alternative seasonal allergy treatments for dogs](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/71/alternative-seasonal-allergy-treatments-for-dogs)
- [What can owners do to help their dachshund's existing back problems?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1229/what-can-owners-do-to-help-their-dachshunds-existing-back-problems)
- [How should I schedule application of flea preventative against bathing?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1352/how-should-i-schedule-application-of-flea-preventative-against-bathing)
- [How can I best manage the drooling from my sick cat?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1322/how-can-i-best-manage-the-drooling-from-my-sick-cat)
- [How can I prevent a dog from removing a splint/bandages?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1226/how-can-i-prevent-a-dog-from-removing-a-splint-bandages)
- [Whether and how to minimise physical activity of female dog immediately following desexing operation?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/90/whether-and-how-to-minimise-physical-activity-of-female-dog-immediately-followin)
- [When is declawing a viable option for cats?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/485/when-is-declawing-a-viable-option-for-cats)
- [Why all the safety concerns regarding topical flea products?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1366/why-all-the-safety-concerns-regarding-topical-flea-products)

Tag Wiki

> The therapy used to cure health or behavioral problems in pets.

Tag Wiki Detail

> Treatment is the method or therapy used to cure health or behavioral problems in pets. This tag can also be used for questions about the application of treatment to pets. This tag should be used along with the pet tag E.g dogs, cats, etc accompanied by the appropriate tag health, behavior, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Treat and Treatment tags](http://meta.pets.stackexchange.com/questions/367/treat-and-treatment-tags)

Comment: Don't think this qualifies as an exact dup, the linked one did touch on treatement, but ended up pluralizing treats - this speaks right to treatment itself.

Comment: Monica; meta up are agree, down are disagree.  If your intent is to remove the "treatment" tag, rephrase your question to something akin to "Should treatment tag be removed or made a synonym?"  I suspect you want it removed, but positive action towards your question preferences keeping it.

Comment: I think it would be good to get people who have worked in Veterinary hospitals to answer.. but then the community doesn't seem to worried about this. I guess it's the general person who is searching, not professionals

Comment: @JoshDM, I know how meta works.  I asked an open question; it's not a specific proposal.  Valid answers include "keep it (because...)" and "no, kill it".  It *feels* like redundant clutter to me, but I'm asking, not pushing.

Comment: Np; +1 I agree that this question should be asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***"treatment"*** has been strategically replaced with any or none of the following based on the question asked: [care](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/care), [medicines](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medicines), [health](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health), [injury](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/injury).  No synonyms provided.

Comment: Awesome. One thing to note, though - as the site gets bigger, we might want to do these changes in stages to avoid flooding the front page and pushing new questions away. It is not that large of a problem at the moment, but something to keep in mind. :)

Comment: @AshleyNunn - Consider that if we get "SO" bigger, a "flood" like that won't be noticed.  Also, questions can always be sorted by latest over activity by entering the questions tab.

Comment: It does get noticed on sites the size of, say, Arqade, which is where my experience is coming from. There, we tend to do things in chunks to not flood the frontpage, because although the questions tab is totally a thing, it is not something everyone uses or is aware of. :) I am not really worried at this point, and love the edits you have been so diligently doing, I just figured maybe mentioning it might not go amiss :)

Comment: N.P.  I find it easier to just do it all at once so I don't forget what the task was.

Comment: In this case there were relatively few questions (8?), but for larger refactorings I agree with Ashley.  Yes there are ways to get around it, but I hate seeing the front page flooded.  I think systematic changes that are going to bump a bunch of questions should be done in batches of 5-10.  If a widely-used tag needs to die, we can request burnination (which doesn't bump questions).

Comment: At least one of the bumped questions got a new answer today, so it's not a total loss.  I did the one that treatment was least applicable to yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

I am of the mind that [treatment](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/treatment) refers to an application, such as a monthly preventative.  There are no other "treatment" scenarios I can imagine that do not involve monthly, potentially prescribed, applications. I believe [treatment](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/treatment) by that definition should be a synonym of [medication](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medication) at best, removed at worst.

Any form of physical therapy should fall under [health](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health) or [care](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/care).

"Treatment" as monthly applications, which should instead use [medication](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medication):

- [Alternative seasonal allergy treatments for dogs](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/71/alternative-seasonal-allergy-treatments-for-dogs)
- [Why all the safety concerns regarding topical flea products?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1366/why-all-the-safety-concerns-regarding-topical-flea-products)
- [How should I schedule application of flea preventative against bathing?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1352/how-should-i-schedule-application-of-flea-preventative-against-bathing)

"Treatment" as direct health care which should probably just use [care](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/care) (optionally [health](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health), but those two are another story altogether) instead:

- [What can owners do to help their dachshund's existing back problems?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1229/what-can-owners-do-to-help-their-dachshunds-existing-back-problems)
- [How can I best manage the drooling from my sick cat?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1322/how-can-i-best-manage-the-drooling-from-my-sick-cat)
- [How can I prevent a dog from removing a splint/bandages?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1226/how-can-i-prevent-a-dog-from-removing-a-splint-bandages)
- [Whether and how to minimise physical activity of female dog immediately following desexing operation?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/90/whether-and-how-to-minimise-physical-activity-of-female-dog-immediately-followin)

Unsure; possibly some sort of [medical-procedure](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medical-procedure) or [surgery](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/surgery) if needed at all

- [When is declawing a viable option for cats?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/485/when-is-declawing-a-viable-option-for-cats)

In some of those deemed [care](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/care), "therapy" is an answer, but not part of the question.  I am of the opinion that tags refer to the question, not the answer; therefore a [therapy](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/therapy) tag or using [treatment](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/treatment) to represent therapy should not be applied.

Comment: I've discovered [tag:injury], which will see some use.

Answer (score 1):

I think we should remove the tag.  As noted in the question, it's being used in lots of different areas -- health, training, and more.  On its own it doesn't mean much, nor is it a useful search term (it's too vague).

I don't think we should make it a synonym; as indicated by the range of questions, there isn't one single thing that it's a synonym of.

Comment: I'ma gonna go nuke this tag.

Comment: Aaaaaand, done.